# Deleting char pointer array

Tags: c++, char, delete-operator

I want to  delete a char * array, which should be simple right? `char * = new char[length];` then use `delete[] char;`?

Also, I am **unable to use `std::string`** for this exercise.

I'm getting this error:

> HEAP CORRUPTION DETECTED: after Normal block (#137) 0x00794B50.
>       CRT detected that the application wrote to memory after end of heap buffer.

Here is my code:

```
class myClass
{
    char * myString;
    ...
public:
    myClass::myClass( const char * tempStr);
};

myClass::myClass( const char * tempStr)
{
    int length = strlen(tempStr);
    myString = new char(length + 1); //+1 for null char
    strcpy(myString, tempStr);
    myString[length] = '\0';
    delete[] myString; //error occurs here
}
```

Now, I know, this code is completely impractical, however it still throws the same error that I am trying to solve so if we can solve this then I should be merrily on my way. From what I've read this should be OK? I'll reiterate, for this exercise I cannot use `std::string`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You messed the brackets up. It should be:

```
myString = new char[length + 1];
```

Square brackets will create an array. Normal brackets will allocate only one with whatever constructor takes that one operand.

Comment: oh i hate myself. Thank you very much, that worked, will mark as answer asap.